# Send mail on a specific date but supress if date changes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, date-time, loop

I have a simple sharepoint list with a user id a deactivation date and a field indicating that the email has been sent.
The goal is for sharepoint to send an email warning the user id that their account has been deactivated on said date. This workflow works fine except if the date is modified, the email is sent on the original date.  For example user ID XYZ is going to expire on 11/10, but if on 11/9 the date is modified to 11/20, the email is still sent on 11/10.   I want sharepoint to recognize the the updated date and supress untill 11/20.  Here's what I setup as my workflow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column and keep it hidden and store the deactivation date in this hidden column. Later when deactivation date is changed you can add a condition to check if the new:deactivation date is not equal to the hidden:deactivation date. If it is not then suppress until the new date is equal to today!

Comment: Thank you.  I'm trying to wrap my head around how that logic would look like in designer.  Can you share?

Comment: @sam It's easier just to recheck (after the pause) whether the deactivation date equals today, and loop if it doesn't. But neither solution would solve the problem of if a de-activation is moved to a prior date rather than to a future date.